# Python string splitting by specific characters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \sentence looks\n \n \nlike\n"
```

Is there a easy way to split the string so that I just get the strings surrounded by \n strings? So that the result would be:

```
['this', 'is', 'what', 'the', 'sentence looks', 'like']
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split()`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \nsentence looks\n \n \nlike\n"
>>> re.split(r'\n\s+', s.strip())
['this', 'is', 'what', 'the', 'sentence looks', 'like']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \nsentence looks\n \n \nlike\n"
print([x for x in s.strip().split('\n') if x.replace(' ', '')])
```

I used list comprehension here. *x* iterates over the string split by the newline character (`"\n"`), and if *x* isn't totally made up of spaces, append it to the list.

Sorry if I didn't explain it very well, my English is not really good.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this in different ways not super clear as to what you wanted although the bottom one should be the best answer you might be looking for.

```
#--- Original code here
text = "\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \nsentence looks\n \n \nlike\n"
print(text)
print('Original')

#--- Modified code 1
text = ['this', 'is', 'what', 'the', 'sentence', 'looks', 'like']
print(text)
print('mod 1')

#--- Modified code 2
text = """this is what the sentence looks like"""
print(text)
print('mod 2')

#--- Modified code 3
text = "\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \nsentence looks\n \n \nlike\n".replace('\n', '')
print(text.split('\n'))

print('mod 3')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use :

```
yourString = "\nthis\n \nis\n \nwhat\n \nthe\n \sentence looks\n \n \nlike\n"
yourArray = yourString.split("\n")
print (yourArray)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score -1):

If for example:

`a = "\nthis\nis\nwhat\nthe\nstring\nlooks\nlike"`

Then syntax is:

```
a = a.split("\n")  
a.remove('')
```

Really hope it helps